# Errors when building maven project via command line

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am trying to build a maven project via the command line. Below is the error I have encountered. I assume that maven is looking for a class `FileSet` which is in `org.apache.maven.shared.model.fileset` package. This file exist in file-management 3.0.0. I downloaded the file and tried but still getting the error. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException:  A
    required class was missing while executing
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean:
    org/apache/maven/shared/model/fileset/FileSet
    ----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.3 strategy =
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] =
    urls[1] = Number of foreign imports: 1 import: Entry[import  from
    realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

    -----------------------------------------------------

        at
    org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:166)
        ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
    org/apache/maven/shared/model/fileset/FileSet   at
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)     at
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)     at
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)    at
    com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
        at
    org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at
    org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)    at
    org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
        at
    org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at
    org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at
    org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at
    org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
        at
    org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
        ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
    org.apache.maven.shared.model.fileset.FileSet   at
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 55 more [ERROR]
```

Comment: How have you called Maven? Which Maven version? Can you post your pom file?

Comment: I was able to get it working by narrowing down the issue by using the -X switch in maven build from command line.